# In Hibernate, how to select several columns as a new class object from multiple joined tables

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, statistics, hql

I'm a rookie in Hibernate. My application should support simple statistics features to select summarized several columns from mutiple joined tables, so I decalred a new class for accepting it and want to return it directly in a HQL, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate entity and non-entity types using JPA constructor expressions i.e. the  `NEW` keyword:

```
List<MyReport> dtos = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.MyReport( o.title, o.version) FROM Entity o").getResultList();
```

The DTO must have a constructor with all the relevant fields.

This is pure JPA, i.e. JPQL. It will work in Hibernate since Hibernate implements JPA. There might be a slightly different or even identical way to do the same with HQL.